# Локальный сервер raspberry pi

Tags: php, linux, сервер, raspberry-pi

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите направление куда копать.

Имеется raspberry pi с OS Rasbian. настроен ngix и php сервер.
Пока это все подключено по lan к компьютеру. по выделенному IP работают страницы 
сайта.
Rasbian будет настроен как точка доступа с открытым паролем.
 теперь сам вопрос:
Можно ли сделать (если да то как) чтобы при подключении к этой сети любого устройства работал локальный адрес. например mysite.ru соответственно только для пользователей этой сети.
и чтобы запросы к другим сайтам редиктились на этот домен/страницу или просто блокировались.

Готовый ответ не прошу. хотябы дайте направление как это называется правильно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=captive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C помощью iptables и PHP можно создать Captive Portal, который будет выполнять эту задачу.
Ссылка: http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal